# How to get current visible image src to fill a field of my form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, web-scraping

In my Rails app, in the form of creation of a new post, I'm using Metainspector to scrap a link and get the images of the website provided.

The response is in ajax and then I use a script that display only one image of a list returned. There are prev and next buttons to loop through them. I want that the visible image's src attribute to be grabbed by jQuery to fill a field of my form.

When I click on prev or next, the content of my field is changed, BUT it displays the previously showed image, not the actual one. I don't know how to trigger that. If I display Image3, I have the src of my Image2 in my field...

What should I add/change in this code to fill the field with the currently displayed source image, and not the previous one ?

Here is the jquery code :

```
var speed = 100;

$(".prev").click(function() {
    var now = $(this).parent().next("ul.gallery").children(":visible"),
        last = $(this).parent().next("ul.gallery").children(":last"),
        prev = now.prev();
        prev = prev.index() == -1 ? last : prev;
    now.fadeOut(speed, function() {prev.fadeIn(speed);});

    var img_src = $('.list_img').children(":visible").attr("src");
    $('#image_url').val(img_src);
});


$(".next").click(function() {
    var now = $(this).parent().next("ul.gallery").children(':visible').addClass("show"),
        first = $(this).parent().next("ul.gallery").children(':first'),
        next = now.next();
        next = next.index() == -1 ? first : next;
    now.fadeOut(speed, function() {next.fadeIn(speed);});

    var img_src = $('.list_img').children(":visible").attr("src");
    $('#image_url').val(img_src);
});

$(".gallery li").click(function() {
    var first = $(this).parent().children(':first'),
        next = $(this).next();
        next = next.index() == -1 ? first : next;
    $(this).fadeOut(speed, function() {next.fadeIn(speed);});
});
```

And the related part of the form in new.html.erb :

```
<%= simple_form_for(@deal) do |f| %>  

<%= f.text_field :link, id: 'link' %>

<div class="slideButtons">
    <span class="prev"><</span>
    <span class="next">/ ></span>
</div>
<ul class="gallery" id="scrap_img">
</ul>

<%= f.text_field :image_url, id: "image_url" %>

<%= f.submit %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of the fadeIn callbacks. What happens is this:

1. You click .prev or .next
2. The old image starts fading out
3. The image_url field is updated with the old (still visible) image's src
4. The old image finishes fading out
5. The new image fades in.

Here's how to redo prev:

```
$(".prev").click(function() {
  var now = $(this).parent().next("ul.gallery").children(":visible"),
      last = $(this).parent().next("ul.gallery").children(":last"),
      prev = now.prev();
      prev = prev.index() == -1 ? last : prev;
  now.fadeOut(speed, function() {
    prev.fadeIn(speed);
    $('#image_url').val($(prev).attr('src'))
  });
});
```

You could also use the DOM to clean up that index-tracking logic, doing something like this (moving the actual elements instead of selectively showing a specific one):

```
$('.prev').click(function) {
  $('.gallery > img').first().fadeOut(speed, function() {
    var newImage = $('.gallery > img').last()
    $(newImage).detach().prependTo('.prev').fadeIn(speed)
    $('#image_url').val($(newImage).attr('src'))
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm getting closer with your DOM solution! I'm now able to grab the current image src into my field. But how can I do to delete the previous images ? When I click to loop through my images, they become visible but don`t disappear. I`ve tried to use a fadeOut but without success.

Comment: fadeOut should do it. It's hard to really comment more without seeing your code base @